# Textbox value will show other textbox information without clicking button

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, search, textbox

this code is working good. But i want to search data without click button. when i will write Employee name if it will exists in table it will show my information otherwise i will insert data. Please help me...

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var sqlQuery = "SELECT EmployeeID, Weight, Amount FROM Supplier where  EmployeeName= '" + TextBox2.Text+ "'";           
    //Create Instance for DataSet
    var DS = new DataSet();
    //Create Instance for SqlConnection
    var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    //Create Instance for SqlCommand
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);


    var DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DS.Clear();
    try{
        DA.Fill(DS);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}

    foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows){
        txtBoxId.Text = row["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        txtboxw.Text = row["Weight"].ToString();
        txtboxam.Text = row["Amount"].ToString();       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you tried adding event on textbox like ontextchanged

Comment: i tried it many days ago...but not works???

Comment: What happened when you tried in the way I suggested you to try

Comment: We can't help you if you just say "not works". Show us exactly what you tried and tell us exactly how it isn't working, THEN we can help you.

Comment: If you are doing it ontextchanged you need to cache it somewhere as it will be use alot of resources

Comment: 1) if you have a large bandwith channel to DB server you can "Select from Database" on TextBox.TextChanged event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.95).aspx).  but this will trigger the DB Server on each modified character. 2) Other alternative can be a little unhandy (trigger the DB Server when TextBox focus is lost. 3) Start a background worker immediately  when start typing, and trigger the DB Server at each time interval you want.

Comment: You could also add your refresh code on a timer event (say every 10 seconds) and if the text box value has changed since the last refresh, then fetch the data again

Comment: @Hamid Has your question been solved? If yes, please mark one of the questions as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TextChanged` event handler and a `parameterized` query for sql injection protection. However, the code below be forwarned is costly because it has to access the Database from time to time.

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
   con.Open();
   String strSQL = "SELECT EmployeeID, Weight, Amount FROM Supplier where  EmployeeName=@EmployeeName";
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con)) 
   {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
     {
        DA.SelectCommand = cmd;
        try
                {
                    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    DA.Fill(DS);
                    foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                      txtBoxId.Text = row["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                      txtboxw.Text = row["Weight"].ToString();
                      txtboxam.Text = row["Amount"].ToString();
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

However, you could probably just cached the whole table and then from there do the query instead of going to the database from time to time like:

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   var query = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<string>("EmployeeName")==TextBox2.Text
            select new
            {
                EmployeeID = myRow.Field<int>("EmployeeID"),
                Weight = contact.Field<int>("Weight"),
                Amount = order.Field<double>("Amount")
            };
    foreach (var row in query)
    {
       txtBoxId.Text = row.Employee.ToString();
       txtboxw.Text = row.Weight.ToString();
       txtboxam.Text = row.Amount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marek for voting up. GOD bless.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a different approach. Assuming the contents of your `Supplier` table do not change frequently, I'd suggest caching the contents of that table on page load and then just reference that table when the text in that text box is changed.

```
private DataTable _suppliers;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         string sqlQuery = "SELECT EmployeeID, Weight, Amount, EmployeeName FROM Supplier";           
         var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
         _suppliers = new DataTable();
         var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
         conn.Open();
         var SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         SDA.Fill(_suppliers);
    }
}

protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(_suppliers);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("EmployeeName LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox2.Text);

    if (DV.Count == 1)
    {
        var row = DV[0];
        txtBoxId.Text = row["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        txtboxw.Text = row["Weight"].ToString();
        txtboxam.Text = row["Amount"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Additionally, you may want to look into using an [updatepanel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1123520.aspx) to handle the text changed event asynchronously instead of using the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)' has some invalid arguments D:\My App\keypress\keypress\key.aspx.cs 21 23 keypress
it is showing like this error

Comment: I edited the code, I didn't actually compile it before so there were some problems

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? What is in _suppliers when you hit the TextBox2_TextChanged event handler?